# Deploy react app to AWS with pm2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, pm2

I am trying to deploy react app to AWS following this tutorial https://medium.com/@sgobinda007/setting-up-react-redux-application-for-production-and-hosting-in-aws-ec2-8bbb8bf3c643 my app is slightly different and when I run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production` I get that app status is online but on `pm2 show` status is errored with the following output: `/home/ubuntu/www/react/tools/distServer.js:4
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
^^^^^^
| 
| SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

my ecosystem.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "blockchainwallet",
        script: "tools/distServer.js",
        watch: true,
        env: {
            "PORT": 8080,
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        env_production: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "production",
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

could you give me any suggestions in order to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your webpack config and the node version of your environment, as the error you mention is a common error for not supported ES6 syntax.

***import*** is used in ES6, you must use ***require*** in ES5

Comment: my node version is 8.10.0 and this is my github https://github.com/scaniusin/reacwithapi 
cannot find where it is mentioned syntax version.

Comment: Under 'tools' directory, in 'distServer.js' try to change all your import from syntax to require syntax (including the destructing of chalkConfig) let me know if that solve that issue

Comment: Yes using require is working but can you help me to understand why, because on my local machine everything is working well?

Comment: The version of Node depends on the machine you deploy the code in... Your computer has one of the latest node version (that includes ES6 syntax) but Amazon server maybe is using a more stable (older) version of Node which doesn't have support for ES6